# how to specify multiple inputs for a command in shell script

Tags: shell, read

I have several fastq files per sample and all of them should be provided at once as an input (as they all belong to one sample, they should NOT be treated independently like in a for loop, as they are inputs for one sample so should be treated together).

This is a simple example when there are only three fastq files for s1 sample:

```
NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq s1.reads1.fastq.gz s1.reads2.fastq.gz s1.reads3.fastq.g --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot
```

Now imagine I have over 100 fastq files for s1, how can I modify the command to have them all as an input?

Comment: How about `NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq s1.*.fastq.gz --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot` ?

Comment: You can read about shell globs here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: Does it matter what order the files are listed in?

Comment: no, it does not

Answer (score 2):

So my suggestion would be to provide a single filename as a parameter to `NanoPlot`, containing the list of FASTQ files, and handle the list in the program accordingly, e.g.

```
NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq fastq_files.list --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot
```

With the contents of `fastq_files.list` as:

```
s1.reads1.fastq.gz
s1.reads2.fastq.gz 
s1.reads3.fastq.gz
...etc
```

Comment: That's a bit harsh to downvote! Since despite the source of the limit being vague, which I have clarified by stating it's a hard coded Linux kernel limit, the problem and solution I proposed is very much valid - and one I have used myself to fix the same issue encountered by the Galaxy Project (https://galaxyproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If this works with `NanoPlot`:

```
NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq s1.reads1.fastq.gz s1.reads2.fastq.gz s1.reads3.fastq.gz --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot
```

and you want to pass all filenames starting with `s1.` and ending in `.fastq.gz`, then a simple shell glob should also work to do that:

```
NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq s1.*.fastq.gz --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot
```

The shell should sort the filenames in the usual lexicographic order, so numbers sort as `1` < `10` < `11` < `2` etc., so take care if that matters.

If you want the program to see a *single* file containing the data from all such files, then you can use a process substitution (in Bash/ksh/zsh) with `cat` to do that:

```
NanoPlot -t 2 --fastq <(cat s1.*.fastq.gz) --maxlength 40000 --plots hex dot
```

Comment: You could use `s1.reads{1..100}.fastq.gz` if you wanted a numerically ordered list, I suppose, provided you knew the lower and upper bounds _and_ the sequence was consecutive. But in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742926/how-to-specify-multiple-inputs-for-a-command-in-shell-script#comment1412228_742926) the OP has said the file order doesn't matter.